# jQuery Google Maps Get Marker By Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I currently have the following code:

```
jQuery.each(json,function(index,value){
            var id =json[index]["id"];
            var location =json[index]["location"];
            var tel =json[index]["tel"];
            var lat=json[index]["lat"];
            var lng=json[index]["lng"];

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              id:id,
              position: new google.maps.LatLng (lat, lng),
              icon: {
                    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                    fillOpacity: 1,
                    fillColor: '#002664',
                    strokeWeight: 1, 
                    strokeColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    scale: 5 //pixels
                },
              map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                jQuery('.office-information').slideUp(300);
                if(!jQuery('#office-info-'+id).is(':visible')){
                    jQuery('#office-info-'+id).slideDown(300);
                }
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            });

            jQuery('.get-direction').on('click', function(){
                var markerID = this.id.replace( /[^\d.]/g,'');
                console.log(marker);
            });

      });
```

The problem area is:

```
jQuery('.get-direction').on('click', function(){
                    var markerID = this.id.replace( /[^\d.]/g,'');
                    console.log(marker);
                });
```

basically, when I click on a link with a class of `get-direction` i grab its id and strip everything but the numbers from it, that leaves me with the markers id. But How do I get a marker by id? I actually just need the latitude and longitude from the marker.

Any Help Greatly Appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a global associative array and store all your markers in there.
E.g. like this

```
var arrMarkers = {};
jQuery.each(json,function(index,value){
    ...
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         ...
    });
    arrMarkers[id] = marker;
    ...
    jQuery('.get-direction').on('click', function(){
            var markerID = this.id.replace( /[^\d.]/g,'');
            console.log(arrMarkers[markerID]);
        });
}
```